# No ViewData Item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key xxxxxx

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a dropdown list in ASP.NET MVC 5 and upon submission I get the above error.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "0" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "1" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text =  "Unconfirmed", Value = "null" });
    ViewBag.DropDown = items;
    return View();
}
```

View code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VisitRequested, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Dropdown, new { onClick = "showHide();" })
```

How would one fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VisitRequested, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Dropdown, 
    new { onClick = "showHide();" })
```

With

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VisitRequested, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Dropdown, "Value", "Text"), 
    new { onClick = "showHide();" })
```

This will fix your issue !!

Comment: Nope. The words System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem appear in the dropdown with the code you have provided.

Comment: @ASPCoder1450, try with the updated one again, it should fix your issue now

Comment: This throws a value can not be null exception at this line

Comment: @ASPCoder1450, The exception occur because you have defined Value = "null" in one of your select list item.

Comment: But the VisitRequested is nullable. There needs to be a null in there

Comment: And thats not the reason because I've replaced "null" with 1 to see if it makes a difference but it didn't

Comment: This code is working fine for me. Can you post the action that handles the submit and the line of code that the error is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "0" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "1" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Unconfirmed", Value = "null" });
            ViewBag.DropDown = items;
            return View();
        }
```

with this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VisitRequested, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.Dropdown, "Value", "Text"), 
    new { onClick = "showHide();" })
```